# how to run turtle graphics in Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

Given that we can do other types of drawing/visualization in Colaboratory, I would think running turtle graphics would be pretty simple (but not so simple I've figured it out!)

I can import the turtle library, but I get the following error when any draw command occurs: 
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think P5.js is your best bet.

I test it in this notebook.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TqF6RObllyslad3KrO4SiAuegRjuJDCF

Answer (score 0):

!pip3 install ColabTurtle

import ColabTurtle.Turtle as t

t.initializeTurtle()

t.forward(50)

t.left(72)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to include the essential 
details/justification of the answer.